# Facebook SEND button blank error

Tags: facebook

We can not create simple HTML with SEND Facebook button that works.

URL that we would like to send to our friends is http://apps.facebook.com/mondobobo .

We have tried HTML 5 and xfbml version of SEND button and neither works.

It returns blank error.

Can someone paste HTML code that will work for him/her with the URL where we can see it working?